# QGIS: Should I convert raster dataset to vector and how?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygonize

I've a raster dataset of 20m² cells that show if a cell has been deforested and the year. I need to calculate the distance of each cell from a conservation project boundary, roads, canals (which are vector layers) and assign slope from a DEM to each cell. I will then export this data and use it in a regression in R. I may need to match cells with similar attributes either side of the boundary too.

To do this, is it best to convert the raster dataset into vector? I am using QGIS and am trying to convert the raster to vector but I'm not sure how to do it or if it's necessary.

I since realised the polygonize tool wasn't showing up for me due to an issue with one of the plugins but am still unsure if I should be converting the data to vector.

Comment: How big is the dataset (cells)?

Comment: It has 5 million cells. I managed to achieve what I was looking for by converting raster to point, then calculating the distance of each point to the conservation boundary

Comment: If you have a solution, answer your own question. That way if someone else comes looking for the same thing they will have something to refer to.